# react.js pass multiple params to arrow function

Tags: parameters, state, render, setinterval, arrow-functions

I want to pass 2 params to arrow function as follows.

```
componentDidMount(){
 setInterval(this.refresh(this.state.firstName,this.state.lastName),1000);
}
refresh = (firstName,lastName)=>{
 console.log(firstName,lastName);
}
```

The log is printed successfully but timeinterval not working.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

React framework automatically add event param to arrow function.
So you should specify it to the function like this:

```
refresh = (firstName,lastName)=>e=>{
 console.log(firstName,lastName);
}
```